# The Unreliable Signal API - Code doesnt work as expected

Tags: c, linux, signals, unix

Basically,expected output of is that it catches KeyboardInterrupt 5 times and exits the 6th time.(If 1st line of **handler() is un-commented**)

> Now, if i comment that line too, then
>   also the behavior of program doesnt
>   change even though I am using
>   unreliable API.

As I have used signal() function, this is unreliable bcos after the first call to the handler(), SIGINT will then have the default behavior, thats is of exiting the a.out..

**The program still quits after 5 ^C.. WHY?**
**

> The code works even without
>   reinstating the handler(). WHy?

**

```
/* ursig1.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
static int count = 0;
void handler(int signo) {
//  signal(SIGINT,handler);
    /* Re-instate handler */
    ++count;
    /* Increment count */
    write(1,"Got SIGINT\n",11); /* Write message */
}
int
main(int argc,char **argv) {
    signal(SIGINT,handler);
    /* Register function */
    while ( count < 5 ) {
        puts("Waiting for SIGINT..");
        sleep(4);
        /* Snooze */
    }
    puts("End.");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a read of the Linux man page for [signal(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/signal.2.html), under the section *Portability*, where it discusses the varying behaviour of signal(2) across the many different versions of Unix. In particular,

> In the original Unix systems, when a
>   handler that was established using
>   signal()  was  invoked  by the
>   delivery of a signal, the disposition
>   of the signal would be reset to
>   SIG_DFL, and  the  system  did  not 
>   block delivery  of  further  instances
>   of the signal.  System V also provides
>   these semantics for signal().

This is the behaviour you are expecting, but it is not what Linux provides, as allowed by POSIX.1. You should be using [sigaction(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) to install your signal handlers to get portable and defined behaviour.